# Return the Column Name for row with last non-null value "Ms Access 2007"

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a Table, which contains a list of league players.  Each season, we record their Points per Dart.  Their total PPD for that season is stored in other tables and extracted through other queries, which in turn are imported to the master table "Player History" at the end of the season for use as historical data.

The current query retrieves  each players PPD for each season they played, when they played last, and how many seasons played.

The code for Last season Played has become too long and unstable to use.  it was originally created, and split into two separate columns because a single SQL was to long. (LSP1) and LSP2) which work, but as I add seasons, Access does not like the length of code.

In short, i need to find a more simple code that will look at each row, and look in that row for the last non null cell and report which column that last non null value is in.

So if a player played seasons 30 & 31, but did not play 32..but did play 33, the Column with the code should be titled Last Season Played, and for that Player, it would state "33" in that cell, indicating that this player last played season "33"

I will provide both tables and the query..

Please help

Comment: Your first query could probably be better solved with a Crosstab.  Your second query should not use the first.  Instead, you should try and solve it earlier in the query chain.  I'm hoping your tables are designed correctly.

Comment: Please contact me, qtrmile69@hotmail.com and i can email the DB.  it's fairly small for this issue only

Comment: If you can wait a few hours, I will email you from home.

Comment: This really sounds like a design problem to me. Robert Harvey mentioned your table design - it sounds to me like poor table design. I'm assuming you're probably just adding a new field for each season which is bad design.